# Trouble parsing JSON feed from REST API call with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest

I have a REST API endpoint that I'm trying to parse using the `$.ajax` call. I can see the JSON structure from the endpoint URL, but can't access the key:value pairs. How can I access "Live" from "type" and the "items" from "sections"? There is not a cross domain issue in this case that would be holding me back. This is my code:

```
<div>
    <p class="type">Type:</p>
    <p class="id">ID</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myrestapiurl.com/"
    }).then(function (data) {
        $('.type').append(data.type);
        $('.id').append(data.items.id);
    });
});
```

JSON response:

```
{
status: {
    code: 200
},
entity: {
    sections: [{
        type: "Live",
        items: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
        entityType: "Section"
    }],
    entityType: "Content"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no data.items.id in the json you specified , though  , you can access that data first like this :

```
     var itemsArray = entity.sections[0].items ;
```

Now , if there is any id field in the items ( in each object )  you can do :

```
    var itemsArray = entity.sections[0].items[0].id ; // 0 is the first object in the items
```

Comment: There is an id in the item object. The fraction of the JSON structure is: 

`entity: {
    sections: [{
        type: "Live",
        items: [{
            id: 967,
            uuid: "4567",
            title: "Title of content",`

I should be able to access the id and title by `data.entity.sections.items.id` correct?

Comment: Nope , check my Edit on answer

Comment: I tried adding `.then(function (data) {
        var itemsArray = entity.sections[0].items[0].id
        $('.type').append(data.entity.sections[0].items[0].id);
        $('.id').append(data.items.id);
    });`

But I'm still not getting the data from the JSON.

Comment: Could you console.log the full JSON , I will help you better then

Comment: I have found a completely separate solution that works much better. Thank you for your input!

Comment: OK , so you can answer your question now , maybe helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had to create another conditional like so:

```
overlays = function(id){
      var returnEL,
          timeline = data.videoJason.entity.stream.timeline;
          _.each(timeline,function(tEl){
            //console.log('id---'.red,tEl);
            if(tEl.id){
              //console.log("tEl.id = ".red, tEl.id, " id = ".red, id, "cond = ".red, (parseInt(tEl.id,10) === parseInt(id,10)));
              if(parseInt(tEl.id,10) === parseInt(id,10)){
                //console.log("id matched cond".red);
                if(tEl.overlays){
                  _.each(tEl.overlays, function(elObj){
                    console.log("OVERLAYS---".red, tEl.overlays)
                    returnEL = tEl.overlays;
                  });
                }
                //console.log('id---',tEl);
              }
            }else{
              returnEL = undefined;
            }
          });

      return returnEL;
    },
```

Then, in the template, use another each statement to parse within the array of objects:

```
        <dt>Overlay:</dt>
        {{#each overlays}}
        <dl class="list-unstyled">
          <li><strong><i>Type:</i></strong> {{type}}</li>
          <li><strong><i>Title:</i></strong> {{title}}</li>
          <li><strong><i>Section:</i></strong> {{section}}</li>
          <li><strong><i>Entity:</i></strong> {{entityType}}</li>
        {{/each}}
```